# Say Hello to User!

Tags: user, login

I have for example "User1" and "User2" and ...
I want that when "User1" logins to the site home page show "Hello User1" and when "User2" comes, it show "Hello User2"
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? Where do you want it? on the masterpage? in a webpart? ...

Comment: Yes... On my masterpage.

Comment: What kind of login do you; FBA? Windows login? TMG?

Comment: I don't know... How should I find it?

Comment: What area do you want this to display? On the ribbon? On the page under the page title, etc? Can you do a screen shot of the page and where you want it and I will tell you how to achieve it. If it is in the ribbon, you need to just simple inject hello before the user name which selected "Preferred Name" first, if you want it in page, you make a simple user control and place it in the correct place, if you want it in the title, then it is also a similar process. Where do you exactly want it to appear?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the most easiest way I know is to show it by JavaScript using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com). Look to [SPServices documentation and examples](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser) for getting current user. This way allows to do that without extra server side codding.

Sample:

```
var thisUserName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldName: "Title",
debug: false
});
```

Then put thisUserName where you need.